# CvCvtColor(srcImage,destImage,CV_BGR2Lab) is not working

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to convert an image from RGB Color space to Lab Color Space in opencv. Hence I used CvCvtColor(srcImage,destImage,CV_BGR2Lab), but the destination image destImage is still in RGB color space it does not get converted to Lab color space..To my knowledge everything is fine than why is this failing.

Thanks
The code is here:

```
 IplImage * img = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iOriginal), iOriginal->depth,iOriginal->nChannels);
 cvCvtColor(iOriginal,img,CV_BGR2Lab);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I have added the code to convert the color space.

Comment: Not completely related to your question. But why use the C implementation instead of the C++ wrapper of OpenCV?

Comment: which one is the C++ wrapper of opencv?

Comment: Well, you are using the C interface of OpenCV right now but OpenCV provides a C++ interface as well: [you might have seen it around](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html): `cv::Mat` instead of `IplImage` and so forth. The C++ equivalent to `cvCvtColor()` is `cv::cvtColor()`

Comment: @karlphillip Yes i know this wrapper but I have to port this application on android and coding in c will be more friendly I think..

Answer (score 0):

A [user named Neon22 reported a problem with CV_BGR2Lab](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/CV-BILATERAL-td5730983.html) some time ago. Not sure it has been fixed since then.